# Error from python worker: /usr/bin/python No module named pyspark

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, biginsights

I am trying to run Pyspark on Yarn, but I receive the following error, when I type any command on the console.

I am able run scala shell in Spark in both local and yarn mode.
Pyspark runs fine in local mode, but does not work in yarn mode.

OS : RHEL 6.x

Hadoop Distribution : IBM BigInsights 4.0

Spark version :1.2.1

> WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, work): org.apache.spark.SparkException:
>   Error from python worker:
>     /usr/bin/python: No module named pyspark
>   PYTHONPATH was:
>     /mnt/sdj1/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/13/spark-assembly.jar ***(My Comment : This path is not present on the linux filesystem,but logical data nodes)***
>   java.io.EOFException
>           at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
>           at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:163)
>           at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:86)
>           at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:62)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:102)
>           at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:280)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:247)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)
>           at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:200)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I have set the SPARK_HOME and PYTHONPATH via export commands, as follows

```
export SPARK_HOME=/path/to/spark
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/spark/python/:/path/to/spark/lib/spark-assembly.jar
```

Can someone please help me out with this ?

## Answer:

## After some digging, I found that pyspark does have some issues in Big Insights 4.0 out of the box.It was suggested that we upgrade to BI 4.1 .